# How to add CComboBox to CDialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm having hard times adding `CComboBox` into my dialog. Whenever I try to add string to the combo I get a failed assertion at this place:

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE int CComboBox::AddString(LPCTSTR lpszString)
    { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return (int)::SendMessage(m_hWnd, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)lpszString); }
```

It seems that combo is not initialized at that time. Here is the code for dialog:

```
#pragma once
#include "afxdialogex.h"

class FeedbackDialog : public CDialog
{
public:
    FeedbackDialog(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);
    virtual ~FeedbackDialog();

    BOOL OnInitDialog() override
    {
        m_comboBox.AddString(L"Super item");
        return TRUE;
    }

#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum {
        IDD = IDD_FEEDBACK_DIALOG
    };
#endif

protected:
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(FeedbackDialog)
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) override;

private:
    CComboBox  m_comboBox;
    int        m_comboSelectedIndex = 0;
};
```

Header:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "FeedbackDialog.h"
#include "resource.h"

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(FeedbackDialog, CDialog)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(FeedbackDialog, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

FeedbackDialog::FeedbackDialog(CWnd* pParent) : CDialog(IDD_FEEDBACK_DIALOG, pParent){}

FeedbackDialog::~FeedbackDialog(){}

void FeedbackDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_CBIndex(pDX, IDC_FEEDBACK_DIALOG_COMBO, m_comboSelectedIndex);
    m_comboBox.AddString(L"Super item");
}
```

I'm trying to open my dialog in modal way:

```
    FeedbackDialog d;
    d.DoModal();
```

Where should I populate my combo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons:

- `m_comboBox` is uninitialized and not bound to the actual control. Use the Class Wizard to add a member variable (`m_comboBox`) of type "Control", rather than "Value". The Wizard will add a `DDX_Control()` call in `DoDataExchange()`.
- `AddString()` should not be called from within `DoDataExchange()`, instead call it from any command-processing handler (eg `OnClickSth()`) or from `OnInitDialog()` - you already have a call there, so just remove the call in `DoDataExchange()`;

If you want the `m_comboBox` variable only for adding the strings, then you don't need to have it in your class permanently. Instead, you can use a temporary object in `OnInitDialog()`:

```
BOOL OnInitDialog() override
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    CComboBox *pCbx = (CComboBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_FEEDBACK_DIALOG_COMBO);
    pCbx->AddString(L"Super item");

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with missing control bounding through `DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_FEEDBACK_DIALOG_COMBO, m_comboBox);`

Comment: @qloq ... and the `m_comboBox.AddString(L"Super item");` in `DoDataExchange` is plain wrong too.

Comment: Adding string in `DoDataExchange` was just for test purpuses.

Comment: It's usually best to create/hook an actual CComboBox object (via the class wizard mechanism or by hand), and not simply cast the CWnd * returned by GetDlgItem.  It may work for "some" calls, but the CWnd * returned by GetDlgItem is NOT a pointer to a fully constructed MFC CComboBox object.

Answer (score 2):

The better way would be to add the control via DoDataExchange

```
void FeedbackDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_FEEDBACK_DIALOG_COMBO, m_comboBox);
    DDX_CBIndex(pDX, IDC_FEEDBACK_DIALOG_COMBO, m_comboSelectedIndex);
}
```

Finaly add the required data in OnInitDialog and call UpdateData again to select the required items.

```
BOOL OnInitDialog() override
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    m_comboBox.AddString(L"Super item");

    // Ahter INIT is done, we select the required item.
    UpdateData(FALSE);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Also possible to check if the DoDataExcahnge is called for the first time and do the init of the data there.

```
void FeedbackDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_FEEDBACK_DIALOG_COMBO, m_comboBox);

    if (!pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate && m_comboBox.GetCount()==0)
    {
        // Init for the first time
        m_comboBox.AddString(L"Super item");
    }
    DDX_CBIndex(pDX, IDC_FEEDBACK_DIALOG_COMBO, m_comboSelectedIndex);
}
```

Than you can leave OnInitDialog as it is.

Comment: Without additional code `OnInitDialog` will be called before `DoDataExchange`, so your second snipped will crash, I have already tried that. You need to call `UpdateData` before adding strings.

Comment: OnInitDialog calls UpdateData that calls DoDataExchange. In DoDataExchange everything is handled there.

Comment: But in your example you call `AddString` before `UpdateData` in `OnInitDialog`

Comment: Wrong. OnInitDIalog calls UpadteDate!

Comment: Ah, holy chupacabra! I got it, sorry!